# The best method of constructing a product of consecutive terms

Tags: expression-construction

I am new to *Mathematica*, I am searching for a way to create an expression with a sequence of terms such as:

```
(x-1)/x  (x-2)/x  (x-3)/x  (x-4)/x … (x-n)/x
```

Comment: Seems like you want `Product[(x - i)/x, {i, n}]`, which yields `(-(1/x))^n Pochhammer[1 - x, n]`

Comment: Please come here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8082/the-newbie-reception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are looking for the best method try symbolic capabilities of `Mathematica`, so  this is the recommended way to go :

```
Product[(x - i)/x, {i, n}]
```

> ```
> (-(1/x))^n Pochhammer[1 - x, n]
> ```

this result might be represented in a different way e.g. using `FunctionExpand` with `TraditionalForm` :

```
Product[(x - i)/x, {i, n}] // FunctionExpand // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

i.e. we have expressed the `Pochhammer` function in terms of the Euler gamma function.
In general one could use simply indefinite `Product` (since the `ver.7` there are also indefinite sums and product), however we have to remember that the convention is the following e.g.

```
Product[n, n]
```

> ```
> (-1 + n)!
> ```

instead of `n!` as one might expect so using an indefinite product would be more complicated to get the result.

Another ways (though not so elegant) use e.g. lists e.g. `Table` or `Range` but then you have to replace a formal variable `n` by a natural number, e.g. :

```
Times @@ ((x - Range[n /. n -> 10])/x)
Unevaluated[ Times @@ ((x - Range[n])/x) == (Product[(x - i)/x, {i, n}])] /. n -> 10
```

> ```
> ((-10 + x)(-9 + x)(-8 + x)(-7 + x)(-6 + x)(-5 + x)(-4 + x)(-3 + x)(-2 + x)(-1 + x))/x^10
>
>  True
> ```

while  with `Product` one can operate on a purely symbolic level.

We had to enclose the equality in `Unevaluated` for several reasons, to examine what might go wrong try to use it without `Unevaluated`. I recommend to take a closer look at the evaluation sequence of the last code line, e.g.

```
Unevaluated[ Times@@((x - Range[n])/x) == (Product[(x - i)/x, {i, n}])] /.n -> 10 //Trace
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'd have used `x^-n FactorialPower[x - 1, n]` or `n! x^-n Binomial[x - 1, n]` myself...

Comment: `Product[(x - i)/x, {i, n}]` is a bit simpler if we are pleased with `Pochhammer`.

Comment: @spaceKnot I'm glad it was helpful however since "That is exactly what I was looking for" I'm curious why it's remained unaccepted.

Comment: @Artes Sorry missed it.