# Is there a function for falling factorial in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions

If I had to construct a function for falling factorial in mathematica I'd do something like that (hope I'm not mistaken):

> fallfact[x_,k_]:=$\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x-j)$

But is there a built-in function for falling factorial in Mathematica?

Comment: `FactorialPower`

Comment: @rasher Nice, I couldn't find it. THank you. You can write your comment as an answer and I'll check it

Comment: Nah, would feel goofy getting points for that :-)

Comment: @rasher just saw that--- lol -- erm, well, I... is this easily found in the documentation?

Comment: ha ha I didn't really know where to find this documentation. I actually went on the MathWorld link you gave in your answer but didn't realize that the function name in Mathematica was written on that page. Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: As "easily" found as anything there, I suppose. I don't recall it being called that anywhere in the docs, I only know it because it's widely known in combinatorics. Would be nice if V10 had a "other names" section of docs...

Comment: Interestingly if I search for "falling factorial" in the *Mathematica* help browser the first link is to the `FactorialPower` page, but "falling" doesn't seem to appear anywhere within that page.  I'm torn between closing this as "easily found in the documentation" and leaving it as a signpost.  What do you both think? ( @rasher )

Comment: Nah, I say leave it, it is rather obscure outside of most fields. Might be a good community wiki (other names and conventions, e.g. the `Pochhammer` in MM is very different from the use in other fields of mathematics). Besides, I can wince as your answer gets 30 upvotes ;-}

Comment: This is closely related: [The best method of constructing a product of consecutive terms](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/the-best-method-of-constructing-a-product-of-consecutive-terms) or just a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html) (a great resource with frequent references to *Mathematica* functions):

> The falling factorial is implemented in *Mathematica* as `FactorialPower[x, n].`
>
> A generalized version of the falling factorial can defined by
>
> $$(x)_n^{(h)}=x(x-h)\cdots(x-(n-1)h)$$
>
> and is implemented in *Mathematica* as `FactorialPower[x, n, h]`.

Documentation: [`FactorialPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FactorialPower.html)